# How to update value and combine columns in csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which contains columns like below. I want to change the date format to 2014-1-10 and combine it with time in a new column. I would like to do this without pandas ...

```
Date     |Time
1/10/2014|0:09:31
1/10/2014|0:10:29
```

The result should look like this:

```
Date     |Time   |DateTime
1/10/2014|0:09:31|2014-1-10 0:09:31
1/10/2014|0:10:29|2014-1-10 0:10:29
```

I tried replace, matrix [][], etc. but somehow nothing works well so far. Will appreciate your help!!

Comment: Avinash, your edit was so fast!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only Python built-int modules:

```
import csv
import os
import datetime

inFilePath = "C:\\Temp\\SO\\test.csv"
outFilePath = "C:\\Temp\\SO\\temp.csv"

inFile = open(inFilePath, "r")
outFile = open(outFilePath, "wb")

reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter='|')
writer = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for row in reader:
    if "Date     " in row:
        writer.writerow(row)
        continue
    newDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    newCell = newDate + " " + row[1]
    row.append(newCell)
    writer.writerow(row)


inFile.close()
outFile.close()

os.remove(inFilePath)
os.rename(outFilePath, inFilePath)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the script but I keep getting "ValueError: time data 'Date    ' does not match format '%m/%d/%y'" error. I wonder what is causing this ...

Comment: @Sumi This happens because different number of trailing spaces after "Date" title. Just use one of the titles as they appear in your code. You can  use "Time" as well". BTW, this is done to skip the first line where column names(titles) are.

Comment: Yeah, that part was solved. Thank you. Now I am facing another error   "data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 14" It looks like time is not parsed correctly??? I am reading some posts about this now ...

Comment: @Sumi Make sure that your data file looks **exactly** like one in your question example.

Comment: Hello Eugene, yup that was my bad - difference of y and Y :-( Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use [PETL](http://petl.readthedocs.org/):

```
import petl as etl
import datetime

t = etl.fromcsv('my.csv')
t = etl.addfield(t, 'DateTime', 
      lambda row: datetime.combine(row[0], row[1]))
etl.tocsv(t, 'mynew.csv')
```

Comment: This looks cool. I installed petl and petlx but Python says 'no module named petl'. I am using Windows (64bit) and Python27. I wonder if it's not compatible with my machine set up?

Comment: I have it up and running in windows with miniconda.

Comment: @Sumi It requires python3 though! That is why

Comment: Oh my... well, I'll try this code one I upgrade to Python3. Thanks!

Comment: I am using petl with Python 2.7. And it also works great in IPython notebook.